# How to validate SVG for the use on the website?

Tags: html, svg, graphics

I've converted PNGs to SVGs, and files I got looks a bit messy. They are huge, there is a lot of HTML code, they cannot be previewed in the IDE I use (PhpStorm), there are issues in the code reported by IDEs etc.

Although these SVGs are loaded and visible in the browsers I use, I was wondering if they are OK to use from the aspect of browser compatibility, accessibility, will they cause some errors which will be detected by bots etc?

Example:
codepen.io/Tahireu/pen/abYERGa

Comment: SVGs are not suitable for images like photos. They are better for simpler images such as line drawings with or without colours which may be graded etc. If your SVG files are huge then, like any huge file, they will not create a good user experience.

Comment: Paste the SVGs into [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/), it will take care of most of the crud. After that, the `<switch>` element will have no more effect. If it still poses problem somewhere, you can safely unwrap its children and remove it.

Comment: Both comments were helpful, thanks.